# Install colcon via 'rosdep install'

Tags: ros, rosdep-install, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm still on ROS1K (about to EoL). Only occasionally trying newer stuff.

If I want to reference `colcon` as a dependency in `rosdep`-sphere, what's the right way to do assuming doing so is NOT out of the range of ROS2 and/or `colcon` framework?

A bit of motivation for me is to allow developers to specify build-tool/system and use `package.xml` for that so that you don't need to specify required/preferred build-tool/system separately (hope I'm interpreting the intent of [buildtool_depend](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0127.html#buildtool-depend-multiple) right).

Trying to find existing references,

- in `rclcpp` (that appeared at the top on `github.com/ros2` org at the time I went there, so I assumed it's up-to-date to the status of ROS2 framework) [it still? uses `ament` in buildtool_depend](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/f5afe380d5f2af5b84b2e64ec54d9afe22ceda99/rclcpp/package.xml#L13). I couldn't find any pkg that refers to `colcon` in buildtool_depend.
- [docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Creating-Your-First-ROS2-Package](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Creating-Your-First-ROS2-Package.html#customize-package-xml) shows `ament` for `buildtool_depend`.

So far I've tried:

- Add ros.org to apt source.
- Add `python3-colcon-common-extensions` (took it from [installation section in colcon.readthedocs.io](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/user/installation.html)) and a few others in `<buildtool_depend>`.

If it's simply that `rosdep` keys for `colcon`-related packages are missing, that's easy. But I'm just not sure if that's the plan.

```
$ docker run -it ros:melodic-ros-base

# cat src/tester_colcon_dep/package.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>tester_colcon_dep</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The tester package</description>
  <maintainer email="root@todo.todo">root</maintainer>
  <license>TODO</license>
<!--  <buildtool_depend>colcon</buildtool_depend> -->
<!--  <buildtool_depend>colcon-ros</buildtool_depend> -->
  <buildtool_depend>python3-colcon-common-extensions</buildtool_depend>
<!--  <buildtool_depend>python3-colcon</buildtool_depend> -->
</package>

# rosdep install -y --from-paths src --ignore-src
:
tester_colcon_dep: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [colcon]

root@46d1b53edc16:/cws# rosdep install -y --from-paths src --ignore-src
:
tester_colcon_dep: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [python3-colcon-common-extensions]

# apt install python3-colcon-common-extensions
:
The following additional packages will be installed:
  javascript-common libjs-jquery libjs-jquery-hotkeys libjs-jquery-isonscreen libjs-jquery-metadata libjs-jquery-tablesorter    libjs-jquery-throttle-debounce libwebpdemux2 libwebpmux3 notification-daemon python3-argcomplete python3-attr python3-catkin-pkg-modules      python3-colcon-argcomplete python3-colcon-bash python3-colcon-cd python3-colcon-cmake python3-colcon-core python3-colcon-defaults      python3-colcon-devtools python3-colcon-library-path python3-colcon-metadata python3-colcon-notification python3-colcon-output
:
(Manually terminated)

root@46d1b53edc16:/cws# more /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros1-latest.list 
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic main


# apt-cache policy python3-colcon-* | ack -A 1 -i installed
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.2.5-1
--                  
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.2.1-1
--                  
  Installed: (none)     
  Candidate: 0.1.0-1
--
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.2.10-1
--
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.0.8-1
--
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.1.1-1
--
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.1.2-1
--
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.2.26-1
--
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.2.7-1
--
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.5.0-1
--
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.2.4-1
--
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.2.13-1
--
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.2.12-1
--
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.3.8-1
--
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.2.1-1
--
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.2.1-1
--
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.3.21-1
--
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.3.3-1
--
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.3.6-1
--
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.2.0-1
--
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.1.0-1
--
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.4.2-1
--
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.6.1-1
--
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.2.2-1

--
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.4.0-1
--
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.2.5-1
--
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.3.3-1
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374424/install-colcon-via-%27rosdep-install%27/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2021-03-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-21**:\

> If it's simply that `rosdep` keys for `colcon`-related packages are missing, that's easy

There are indeed [no rules for Colcon](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/36b9d77b343a5f751557d797fd3c2d212554d485/rosdep/python.yaml) currently.

As to why you don't see `colcon` as a `buildtool_depend`: afaik, Ament is the replacement / successor to Catkin -- the CMake side to it, that is.

Colcon is the successor to Catkin -- the build tool, that is.

The two Catkins are related, but not identical.

Compare how "Catkin packages" can be built using plain CMake (`mkdir build && cd build && cmake ..`), `catkin_make`, `catkin_make_isolated` and `catkin_tools` (and Colcon).

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2021-03-22**:
Never thought about those 2 aspects! In `ros1`, `buildtool_depend` is `catkin`, with which I should've noticed it is about CMake aspect (though this is very tricky to decode). Anyways, now that I've started thinking using `buildtool_depend` to specify build tool (in the sense documented in http://design.ros2.org/articles/build_tool.html) like `colcon` might be not appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No idea how this will go, but I suggested a rosdep key for `colcon` [rosdistro!28923](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/28923).

The `rosdep` key for `colcon` is "`python3-colcon-common-extensions`".

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2021-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2021-04-16**:
https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/28923 is accepted, so I guess that was it.